# How do I know user who changed his display name

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I was looking for some answer and comments on a question where I found that there are tags to some users who are not in the comments.

I first thought the users deleted their accounts but I realized that the display names were changed.

How would I know for example when I check the users page ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)) that some users change their display names (I just guessed using the reputation and some other info in the user's accounts to know who is)

Comment: Only moderators can see the full history of a user's display names. Others will have to use memory or context/links to figure it out.

Comment: @TheToad, thanks. I remember now:)

Comment: Closely related [question](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/897/3066)

Comment: @m_goldberg it is not closely related, I can say it is a duplicate. the question answered what I asked about. Thanks

Comment: @TheToad Or just **guess**

Comment: There's the [WayBack Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://mathematica.stackexchange.com).  Searches don't work (it seems), but the "Users" button does.

Comment: The chat preserves old user names, but links them to the current account.

Comment: …that is, if the user in question also participates in the chatroom.

Answer (score 5):

Use [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29863189/mse/usernames.html) to recover the list of former names for a given user.

Comment: It is not completely accurate, but it does help. +1

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yeah, nice. [Except for the fact that you may become slightly paranoid](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yFhfy.png)

Comment: @belisarius hmm, I had not noticed that as I used my meta user as a test. Apparently I have been called `FilterRules` in the past. I've been called worse things, but...

Comment: The link is dead.